# Unable to get data in dropdown in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have a requirement like, i need to display data from database to dropdown. Till action class the data is displaying and even it is getting display in Action class. But when it come to jsp. Dropdown is empty.

**jsp tag here**

```
html:select property="strName" tabindex="1">
<html:option value="">-- Select --</html:option>
<logic:notEmpty name="NameList">
<html:optionsCollection  name="PinRequestActionForm" property="NameList" label="pinrequestVO.strNameCD" value="pinrequestVO.strNameId" />
</logic:notEmpty>
</html:select>
```

Please suggest me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Do you have a property for named list?

Answer (score 0):

*If the data is added in the NameList you can display using the `<logic:iterate>` tag:*

`<html:select property="strName" tabindex="1">
<logic:iterate id="x" name="NameList">
<html:option value='${x.strNameId}'>${x.strNameCD}`
`</html:option>
</logic:iterate>
</html:select>`

Answer (score -1):

I have refered this link.
http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/JSP-Servlet/29460-how-to-get-data-from-database-into-dropdownlist-in-jsp.html

Use this servlet code in your program.

```
Customer Name:

<select name="name">
     <% 
     try{

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/scs","root","root");

        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        String sql="select * from staff";
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()){
         //String name = rs.getString("name");
     }
   %>
   <option value="<%=rs.getString("fname")%>"></option>

     <%
        }catch(Exception e){
        }     
     %>

 </select>
```

Comment: This is an inappropriate solution for a multitude of reasons.